# Finding zeros of a function with an $i$ constant

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to show that the zeros of $$f(z)=z^4+3iz^2+3$$ lie in the disk $\{z \in \mathbb{C}:|z| \le \sqrt{4} \}$

I'm using Rouche's theorem. Here's where I'm stuck. I let $g(z)=3iz^2$ for $|z|=2$, so that $$|f(z)-g(z)|=|z^4+3| \le |z|^4+3=19$$. How do I show that this is less than $g(z)=12i$ for $|z|=2$? Do I have to use the definition of magnitude so that this is $144$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here in my book, it is stated as

> if $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ are analytic functions inside and on a closed curve $\gamma$ and if $|f(z)| < |g(z)|$ for all $z$ on $\gamma$, then $f(z)+g(z)$ and $f(z)$ has same number of roots of zeros inside $\gamma.$

It seems that same is stated in [mathworld site](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RouchesTheorem.html). And a different on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%27s_theorem), probably the other answer will suite your question.

Let $|f(z)| \le |z^4|+|3iz^2|+|3| \le 31 < |2z^4| - 1 \le |2z^4 - 1| = |g(z)|$, and $g(z)$ has four roots in $|z| < 2$.

Comment: Ah my professor uses this version: $|f(z)-g(z)|<|g(z)|$

Comment: Very nice though didn't know you could do it this way either

Comment: @User69127 Since my book claims $f(z) + g(z)$ and $f(z)$ will have same number of roots, I think we can transform $f(z) \to f(z) + g(z)$ which will give the same result.

Answer (score 2):

Notice 
$$
|z^4+3|\ge 16-3>|3iz^2| \quad\text{when } |z|=\sqrt{4}.
$$
So $z^4+3iz^2+3$ and $z^4+3$ have the same number of roots in $|z|<\sqrt{4}$.